# linq data is grouped / hierachical

Tags: c#, linq

I want to query a hierachical dataset to retrieve a certain element (hosts).
I want this result to be flat (`List<Host>`)

My data is hierachical: 
`clusters`
    - `hosts`
          -`guests`

I have the following linq query:

```
var clusteredhosts = from c in dataViews.Clusters select c.Hosts;
```

I was hoping to get a `List<Host>` result back, but instead I get a `List<List<Host>>`. This obviously makes sense as it returns a grouped result `<cluster, hosts>`, but it's not my desired output.

How can I in my case make this a flat structure? `List<Host>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of query expression you can use lambda expression.

```
var clusteredhosts = dataViews.Clusters.SelectMany(c=>c.Hosts);
```